# AWS REDCap installation error DBParameterGroupFamily aurora-mysql5.7 cannot be used

Tags: amazon-web-services, redcap, aws-rds-data-service

I installed REDCap from this github [launch stack](https://github.com/vanderbilt-redcap/redcap-aws-cloudformation) button. For the first time installation it went good and installed the necessary stack without any issue. However, due to some other issues with existing installation I decided to install another stack while the first stack is still running. Now when I try to install 2nd stack then each time AWS is failing to create the stack. It fails on the step of creating RDSCluster with the following error

> Resource handler returned message: "The Parameter Group
> myredcap-redcapelasticbeanstalk-8vqa1np5heic-rdsdbclusterparametergroup-aa5gopncdfmo
> with DBParameterGroupFamily aurora-mysql5.7 cannot be used for this
> instance.

> Please use a Parameter Group with DBParameterGroupFamily
> aurora-mysql8.0 (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
> 58f593d8-f517-4d33-8f64-99bfa39041a5)" (RequestToken:
> 3ac10d04-a94f-89d1-fab2-2ced450ae3fd, HandlerErrorCode:
> InvalidRequest)

I didn't create any DBParameterGroupFamily by myself and when stack is being created then I see following screen shot

[image]

The scripts to create the stack are 3rd party so I can not modify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get latest changes in the template from Vanderbilt. Please refer below commit id for more details,

https://github.com/vanderbilt-redcap/redcap-aws-cloudformation/pull/32/commits/c6cb3baaa8326b273ce088c24477386d09fece23

If you are running the latest template now it should work.